# looking best notation for UML Class diagram

Tags: class, uml, class-diagram, use-case

I have the following problem to resolv. Given the following UML diagram:

[image]

I need to complete the diagram doing the following steps:

a) When an employee has a skill, the relationship between the employee and the skill shows years of experience.

b) A worker may have another employee as a manager and a worker who is a manager must manage five or more workers. As a manager, you can determine which workers he manages, but a worker can not determine who is his manager.

c) An activity can have a maximum activity precedent and any number of upcoming activities. Using these roles, we can show how the activities are arranged. Given an activity, you can only determine their own activities (if you have), but not what your previous activity (if any).

d) A worker is not simply associated with a set of skills, but a worker has skills. In particular, every worker should have three or more skills, and any number of employees can have the same ability.

e) A project is not simply a set of activities associated with, but contains a project activities. Specifically, a project must have one or more activities, and activity must belong to exactly one project.

f) Projects and activities are a specific type of job.

My solution is shown in the following picture, but because I am new in this I would like to check if is fine.

[image]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: "but a worker can not determine who is his manager" - where does that happen? North Korea?

Comment: hahaha, I know!, but is how the exercise has been given to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks good in most parts. Honestly I don't understand the later parts of c)

Your `-boss` relation is wrong. Your Northern Koreans should not have a private known boss. Instead there's only the other way around and the boss has - let's call them - `-slaves`. If you put in a private `-boss` it actually means that the `slave` can navigate to its private boss which is explicitly not wanted. Only the boss shall know the one he's responsible for. So actually the object itself is the `boss` object. As a thought, since only the boss should have those 5 employees, it could be an idea to create a separate boss object like this:

[image]

Note that this might also have drawbacks since `Boss` is now actually a different object than `Employee`, but it seems to fit the requirements.

Point f) seems to call for a generalization. So you would need a generalization towards `SpecificJob`. This would be an arrow with open triangle, not the one you used:

[image]

This actually reads `Project` and `Activity` are specific kinds of `Job` as they both inherit from the latter.

Comment: Why the -boss relation is wrong? In the description says that worker cannot determine who is his manager. That is why I have used the arrow and the property - in the role.

Comment: Also, Can I do a generalization from two clases toward another? Shouldn't I take into account the relation between Project and Activity?? Thank you!

Comment: I just have elaborated on my answer.

Comment: Thank you, Thomas Kilian. I am not really sure about your solution, but I will take into account.

Comment: Which part is it you're not sure of?

Comment: Let's see, the part of c) means: With the given activity you can only determine the next activity (if you have any), but not what the previous activity was (if they had one).
On the other hand, in the study material I have, it says that when you add the simbol "-" you dont allow the visibility to that role and the arrow forces the navigation only in one direction, so that is why I used a reflexive relation in employee. You need to think that the exercise was given with those entities, so I can add more, but not delete them or change them for others.

Comment: Sorry, I know is a tongue twister :/

Comment: The `-` just tells about the scope. So if I have a `-preceding` I can see my own preceding activity, but not the precedent of that one. But your requirement says that the activity *itself*  shall not see its precedent. And that can only be realized by not having a `precedent` attribute at all. It sounds as academic as the also strange `slave` relation.